# Beamer PDF export: title, subtile, content show one by one

Tags: org-mode, org-export, beamer

Say, in a slide I have

```
* title
** subtitle
   content
```

They will appear in the same slide with default beamer export.

What I want to achieve is exporting it to three slides with first page only `title`, second page `title` and `subtitle`, finally third page with all these three elements.

I know this can be achieved within list items.

```
- <1-> first item
- <2-> second item
- <3-> third item
```

But how can I achieve this with title and subtitle, and even subsubtitle and content?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use pauses:

```
* title
#+BEAMER: \pause
** subtitle
#+BEAMER: \pause
   content
```

Comment: Thx, this works!